# C++ How to generate 10,000 UNIQUE random integers to store in a BST?

Tags: c++, random, binary-search-tree, unique, random-seed

I am trying to generate 10,000 unique random integers in the range of 1 to 20,000 to store in a BST, but not sure the best way to do this.

I saw some good suggestions on how to do it with an array or a vector, but not for a BST. I have a `contains` method but I don't believe it will work in this scenario as it is used to search and return results on how many tries it took to find the desired number. Below is the closest I've gotten but it doesn't like my `==` operator. Would it be better to use an array and just store the array in the BST? Or is there a better way to use the below code so that while it's generating the numbers it's just storing them right in the tree?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) 
{
    int random = rand() % 20000;
    tree1Ptr->add(random);
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (tree1Ptr[j]==random) i--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle  And unique numbers are almost by definition not random.

Comment: That seems like two different problems to me. Inserting into a binary search tree and creating the numbers that are not in the tree seem unrelated. What type of container you use shouldn't really make a difference.

Comment: Shouldn't a collection.contains(x) method return a binary value whether or not collection contains x or not? your variant makes little sense.

Comment: *" it doesn't like my == operator"* Is it that or `operator[]` on whatever `tree1Ptr` is?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems in your code.  But let's go straight to the hurting point.

**What's the main problem ?**

From your code, it is obvious that `tree1Ptr` is a pointer.  In principle, it should point to a node of the tree, which has two pointers, one to the left node and one to the right node.

So somewhere in your code, you should have:

```
tree1Ptr = new Node;   // or whatever the type of your node is called
```

However, in your inner loop, you are just using it as if it was an array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) 
{
    int random = rand() % 20000;
    tree1Ptr->add(random);
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (tree1Ptr[j]==random)  //<============ OUCH !!
            i--;
    }
}
```

The compiler won't complain, because it's valid syntax:  you can use array indexing on a pointer.  But it's up to you to ensure that you don not go out of bounds (so here, that j remains <1).

**Other remarks**

By the way,  in the inner loop, you just want to say that you have to retry if the number is found. You can `break` the inner loop if the number is already found, in order not to continue.

You should also seed your random number generator, to avoid running the program always with the same sequence.

**How to solve it ?**

You really need to deepen your understanding of BST. Navigating through the node requires make comparison with the value in the current node, and depending on the result, iterate continuing either with the left or the right pointer, not using indexing.    But it would be too long to explain here. So may be you should look for a tutorial, like [this one](https://hub.packtpub.com/binary-search-tree-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

For a lot of unique 'random' numbers I usually use a [Format Preserving Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption).  Since encryption is one-to-one, you are guaranteed unique outputs as long as the inputs are unique.  A different encryption key will generate a different set of outputs, i.e. a different permutation of the inputs.  Simply encrypt 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... and the outputs are guaranteed unique.

You want numbers in the range [1 .. 20,000].  Unfortunately 20,000 needs 21 bits and most encryption schemes have an even number of bits: 22 bits in your case.  That means you will need to cycle walk; re-encrypt the output if the number is too big until you get a number in the desired range.  Since your inputs only go up to 10,000 and you will be cycle walking above 20,000 you will still avoid duplicates.

The only standard cipher I know of which allows a 22 bit block size is Hasty Pudding cipher.  Alternatively it is easy enough to write your own simple [Feistel cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher).  Four rounds are enough if you do not want cryptographic security.  For crypto level security you will need to use AES/FFX, which is NIST approved.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways where you can pick random unique numbers out of a sequence **without** checking against the numbers previously picked (i.e. already in your BST).

#### Use random_shuffle

A simple way is to shuffle a sorted array of 1 ... 20,000 and simply pick the first 10,000 items:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> values(20000);
for (int i = 0; i < 20000; ++i) {
  values[i] = i+1;
}
std::random_shuffle(values.begin(), values.end());

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
  // Insert values[i] into your BST
}
```

This method works well if the size of random numbers (10,000) to pick is comparable to the size of total numbers (20,000), because the complexity of random shuffling is amortized over a larger result set.

#### Use uniform_int_distribution

If the size of random numbers to pick is much smaller than the size of total numbers, then an alternative way can be used:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

// Use timed seed so every run produces different random picks.
std::default_random_engine reng(
    std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());

int num_pick  = 1000;   // # of random numbers remained to pick
int num_total = 20000;  // Total # of numbers to pick from

int cur_value = 1;  // Current prospective number to be picked
while (num_pick > 0) {
  // Probability to pick `cur_value` is num_pick / (num_total-cur_value+1)
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distrib(0, num_total-cur_value);

  if (distrib(reng) < num_pick) {
    bst.insert(cur_value);  // insert `cur_value` to your BST
    --num_pick;
  }
  ++cur_value;
}
```